# How can I create a never ending IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

I use a service to continuously synchronize information to display on the activity. The service runs an endless loop *while(true)* in which the information is updated every 10 seconds. In some devices the service stops after a time of execution. How I can keep the task of the intentService running? It must run even if the user minimize the application.

Comment: Excuse me, the subject of your question says the opposite of your question. Or put before: "How to" and a question mark at the end.

Comment: "I... continuously synchronize information... every 10 seconds" -- if by "synchronize", you mean synchronize with some server over the Internet, why do you think that this is a good idea? Android is going to great lengths to prevent apps from doing this sort of thing, because users value battery life.

Answer (score 3):

You shoudn't do that (and you even can't since android 6.0: [doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)). Consider using [cloud messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to notify your app that something has changed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

A `Service` is ideal for hosting long-running processes that outlive any one activity.  If you're just displaying the data, as opposed to saving it or doing some kind of background processing with it, there's no reason to use a `Service` at all.  Just use `Handler#postDelayed(...)` in the activity, and make sure the task is removed on pause.

Polling every ten seconds is probably excessive.  In fact, polling at all is probably inefficient, unless you expect the data to change as frequently as you are polling.